# Как убрать "всплывающие подсказки" в редакторе VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Использую VS Code для Python. Все хорошо.
Только не нравятся всплывающие подсказки, которые появляются при наведении курсора мышки на любую переменную/функцию/класс.
Вот, к примеру, как на картинке:
[image: Всплывающая подсказка]
Как их отключить?

Comment: Да, как их хотя бы сместить, они реально бесят. ты пишешь код а тут раз сумрак пришел и закрыл собственно место куда я пишу, злости не хватает. И огромное желание вернуться на sublime.

Comment: Вы нашли решение "всплывающие подсказки" ?

Answer (score 8):

Сегодня прилетело обновление 1.25.0

Опция:

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
```

... убирает всплывающие подсказки.

Answer (score 3):

Заходишь в настройки, параметры, ищешь hover, отключаешь галочки про документацию и подсказки для каждого языка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

1. Переходишь: `File (Файл) -> Preferences (Параметры) -> Settings (Параметры)`.
2. Находишь: `python.linting.pylintEnabled` и устанавливаешь значение `false`.

**P.S:** Также можно отключить все подсказки сразу: `"editor.parameterHints": false`

Comment: 1. Перешел. Там есть строка поиска. вбил в нее "python.suggest", пишет - "нет результатов"

Comment: 2. "editor.parameterHints": false - уже стоит. Не помогает. Весь день сегодня пытаюсь решить этот вопрос.

Comment: @Evg, возможно это зависит от pylint. Попробуй `"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false`

Comment: Ares God, "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false - тоже уже стоит... Пробовал и в "Настройках пользователя", и в "Настройках рабочего пространства"... бесполезно. Что характерно, эти окошки "всплывают" и когда водишь курсором мышки над параметрами настройки... Но вот в html файлах этих подсказок Нет. (других типов файлов, из других языков - не редактировал)

Comment: @Evg, а ты перезагружал VS Code или Ctrl+Shift+P - Reload Window?

Comment: Ares God, конечео :) Более того - пробовал на двух разных компах. Правда на них и плагины и настройки одинаковые... Подозреваю, что если другим помогает "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false, то надо будет заново начисто ставить VSCode, добавлять плагины, и смотреть когда появятся подсказки. Ну, чтобы вычислить, что там "портит". А у Вас эти подсказки всплывают или нет?

Comment: @Evg сейчас установил, и после pylint disabled, подсказки не всплывают

Comment: Ares God, ок, понял, спасибо! Буду завтра начисто ставить. Видимо какой-то плагин оказывает "медвежью услугу"

Comment: @Evg пробуйте:)

Comment: В общем, дела такие. МакОс (может это важно). Удалил VSCode. Удалил все настройки и расширения. Поставил его начисто. Подсказок над кодом .py - не всплывало. Работать уже было можно, но не фурычило автодополнение из виртуальной среды (ну и еще много чего). Поставил плагин Python 0.9.1 - сразу полезли подсказки. Установил в false и python.linting.pylintEnabled и editor.parameterHints - не помогло! подсказки так и прут. Может косяк версии под мак. Так что вопрос пока открыт.

Comment: @Evg, странно. Проверил еще раз: автодополнение работает, хинты не показываются (Win10). Да, возможно проблема в версии под MacOS (хотя маловероятно, ибо используется Electron, который кросс-платформенный)

Comment: Ares God, Сама то среда VSCode может и нормально работает. Изначально там есть поддержка python. Но в версии по умолчанию у меня не работало автодополнение из виртуальных сред. Поэтому поставил плагин Python 0.9.1... и вот тут, сразу, полезли хинты над кодом. То есть я даже не настраивал плагин. Попробовал отключить указанные опции - не помогает. Скорее всего, все-таки, для МакОс все-таки различия в чем-то есть. Может в плагине. Ладно, буду пока так жить. В остальном всё совсем неплохо.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто.
File (Файл) -> Preferences (Параметры) -> Settings (Параметры)

В открывшемся окошке видим поле для ввода, что ищем. 
Забиваешь туда hint.
В настройках сразу отображаются чекбоксы с галочками, которые отвечают за надоедливые всплывающие подсказки. Снимаешь галочку там, вот и все. )